# Automate Unique ID On Class & Help Make Each Button Separately Modifiable

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, class

I'm using wordpress, I've a content box plugin WP Boxer, I would like to take control of each individual button in each box created.
So I wanted to create a separate class for every button, right now they are all under the same class.

Here's how it is now:

```
$box['content']['text'] = $excerpt. '<div class="clearboth"></div>
<a href="'. get_permalink(). '" class="bttn">'. sprintf('%s &raquo;', __('Read More', WPBOXER_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN)). '</a>'. trim( $block_link );
```

And this is what i tried but it didn't work

```
$box['content']['text'] = $excerpt. '<div class="clearboth"></div>'
            $i = 0;
            if ( count($links) > 0 ) {
                foreach( $links as $id ) {
            <a href="'. get_permalink(). '" class="bttn<?php echo $i; ?>">. sprintf('%s &raquo;', __('Read More', WPBOXER_ADMIN_TEXTDOMAIN)). '</a>'. trim( $block_link );
            $i++;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try including

```
id="<?php echo $i; ?>"
```

inside the tag instead of putting it in the class

Comment: When i do that nothing happens, do i need to put something in the id=" $id" ?

Comment: Is it displaying the links and just not rendering the php or is it not displaying anything?

Comment: it gives the same output as before and under id its not displaying anything

Here's the website: http://websample.host56.com/

I am trying to get hold of each green button so i can modify their CSS individually.

Comment: ok done, i just used CSS Selector as perma link

a[href$='89'] {
position: relative;
top: 20px;